# Extend @types/node with custom project environment variable type decelerations

Tags: node.js, typescript, environment-variables, dotenv, .d.ts

I have a project that uses [**`dotenv`**](https://npmjs.com/package/dotenv) for environment variables, and I want to add custom project-specific typings for the variables the project uses, for autocompletion, etc.

How can I do this without overriding all the stuff that [**`@types/node`**](https://npmjs.com/package/@types/node) already does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can augment the `ProcessEnv` interface which is the type of `process.env`:

```
// node.augmentations.d.ts
declare namespace NodeJS {
    interface ProcessEnv {
        db: string
        port: string
    }
}

//otherfile.ts
process.env.port //suggested
process.env.db // suggested
process.env.dbb // still ok
```

This approach will give you auto-completion, although it will not prevent you from accessing other members on `env` since `ProcessEnv` defines an index signature.

Comment: Where would I put that file in my project?

Comment: @JamesJensen don't know what your project structure is. If you have any other custom typings I would put this with those, otherwise a folder `types` in your `src` folder is what I usually go with ..

Comment: I'm getting the linting error `Top-level declarations in .d.ts files must start with either a 'declare' or 'export' modifier.`

Comment: @JamesJensen That is a tslint error, I can't really foresee what tslint configuration you use. The code above is valid TS code. You can add a `declare` to the namespace. Since the `namespace` only contains an interface it will not make much difference in this case